# Asp.Net Default aspnetdb.mdf

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

When you create a new ASP.NET project with membership it creates the default connection string for `ApplicationServices` as follows:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Is there a way to force this to use SqlServerCe in the `App_Data` folder instead of creating it in sql express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no its not possible, but you can check it  via code for data source..